# Deleting default value from helm values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am deploying a third party app called [zeebe](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-platform-helm/blob/main/charts/camunda-platform/values.yaml) through helm. I want to remove certain attributes from the deployment that get set through the values.yaml. I tried setting them null both in the values.yaml and in the helm install command but it didn't help.

```yaml
global:
  labels:
    app: null
```

`helm install dev camunda/camunda-platform -f camunda-local.yaml --set global.labels.app=null`

Trying to understand the helm chart, I see that these labels are used in the `_helpers.tpl` file [here](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-platform-helm/blob/main/charts/camunda-platform/templates/_helpers.tpl#L49). They (labels) then get added as labels to the stateful set created during deployment which I want to avoid.

Further testing I realised that if I download the complete helm chart locally and mark the above attribute as `null` in the values.yaml file then the label is skipped as expected in the statefulset. I don't understand why it works when the helm chart is local but this solution isn't feasible because it requires us to maintain the helm chart locally.

Can you please guide me how can I delete this attribute?

Thanks.

Comment: How does this value get used?  Can you [edit] the question to include the Deployment template, and any other details needed for a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidMaze - I have added reference to the helm chart code that reads this property. I can see a `matchLabels` function that is reading the tables and adding to the yaml. Also added details about local tests being done.